# bootbox confirm before ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootbox

I have this Javascript code:

```
this.confirmBox = function(event, data) {
  return bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
    alert(result); // this returns TRUE as it is supposed to
  });
};

this.beforeSend = function(event, jqXHR) {
  if (this.confirmBox()) {
    // HERE THE AJAX QUERY GETS EXECUTED
  } else {
    return jqXHR.abort(); // HERE WE ABORT IT
  }
};
```

My problem is that the ajax query gets executed before I confirm within bootbox popup. How do I need to change the line `(this.confirmBox())` in order to have the beforeSend function checking if the confirmBox function returns true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the this.beforeSend inside the function(result).... of the confirm box

Comment: Does not work. The ajax call is still made once the bootbox is loading  async.

Comment: Please revise the original question with the new code so I can see what you wrote and what is not working

Comment: Problem is that even when i completely remove the beforeSend function the ajax request is executed. The original script is using the natve confirm popop which is preventing the ajax from executing until confirmed. With any of the plugins I tried now (bootbox, jconfirm & jquery.msg) i am unable to achieve the same result.